# Subscript out of range on Class

Tags: arrays, vba, class

I created this class named "CInventory". This class generates an array of "valid data". To see this array on a range I tried to "paste" the array to see the result. I get a "subscript out of range". The error appears on line 6 (cinv.AllocateInventoryData) of the simple module.

This is the Class Module called CInventory:

```
Option Explicit
Private Path As String
Private TextFileNumber As Integer
Private InventoryData() As String

Public Property Get GetInventoryData() As String
    GetInventoryData = InventoryData
End Property

Public Property Let SPath(Text As String)
    Path = Text
End Property

Public Sub AllocateInventoryData()
    Dim ColumnArray() As String
    TextFileNumber = FreeFile
    Dim FileContent As String
    Dim i, j As Integer
    j = 0
    Open Path For Input As TextFileNumber
    FileContent = Input(LOF(TextFileNumber), TextFileNumber)
    Close TextFileNumber
    ColumnArray() = Split(FileContent, vbCrLf)
    For i = LBound(ColumnArray) To UBound(ColumnArray)
        If IsValidRow(ColumnArray(i)) Then
            ReDim Preserve InventoryData(j, 4)
            InventoryData(j, 0) = Left(ColumnArray(i), 8)
            InventoryData(j, 1) = Trim(Mid(ColumnArray(i), 10, 8))
            InventoryData(j, 2) = Trim(Mid(ColumnArray(i), 19, 18))
            InventoryData(j, 3) = Trim(Mid(ColumnArray(i), 57, 2))
            InventoryData(j, 4) = Trim(Mid(ColumnArray(i), 60, 12))
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Private Function IsValidRow(Text As String) As Boolean
    If Left(Text, 6) = "iclorp" Or Left(Text, 5) = "Page:" Or Len(Trim(Text)) < 3 _
    Or Left(Text, 4) = "Site" Or Left(Text, 6) = "------" Then
        IsValidRow = False
    Else
        IsValidRow = True
    End If
End Function
```

And this is the Module from which I call the class CInventory (simple module)

```
Option Explicit
Sub example()
    Dim cinv As CInventory
    Set cinv = New CInventory
    cinv.SPath = "H:\Joel\invent_2.prn"
    cinv.AllocateInventoryData   '<-- here appears the error
    Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1) = cinv.GetInventoryData
End Sub
```

Comment: Please click the edit button below your question then take a moment to properly indent your code so that it can be read easily.

Comment: Add error handling to ```AllocateInventoryData``` and debug it. You will see the problem and the exact line where the ```Subscript out of range``` occures.

Comment: Looks like your IDE is skipping errors in class modules. Bring up the Tools/Options dialog, under the General tab, in the Error Trapping section. Check the "Break on all errors" option.

Comment: @JoeJoe I think you error comes from the part where you use the function `Mid(ColumnArray(i), 10, 8)`, for example, in the `For` loop of your `AllocateInventoryData()` procedure. The error occurs when the string in `ColumnArray(i)` is too short. For example, If `ColumnArray(i)` has 15 characters and you call `Mid(ColumnArray(i), 10, 8)`, you will get a `Subscript out of range` error because, starting from the 10th character, you are trying to extract 8 more when there are only 5 remaing. The same errors can occur when calling the function `Left()` too!

Comment: I did try your proposal @OscarAnthony but it was not the problem, I edited the function IsValidRow as here:
`If Left(Text, 2) = "MX" Then IsValidRow = True` leaving all those stuff of "OR's" but still the problem

Comment: Shouldn't you define i and j as Long? `Dim i As Long, j As Long` What you have for i is a Variant. It should have converted by LBound anyway. perhaps you can put a break point in `AllocateInventoryData`, step thru it and observe?

Comment: The line that is throwing Error 9 is `ReDim Preserve InventoryData(j, 4)`. You cannot ReDim the 1st dimension.

Comment: no i should not @Patrick, i did not require that amount of memory, with a integer was enough, and for the second you were right, i did try to redim the first argument, and now i redim the second ( I have to transpose it, and then re-transpose again in a module ) , thank you all for your help, every comment did help me : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the answer!, after a while but it works as I wanted

The class module 'CInventory'

```
Option Explicit
Private Path As String
Private TextFileNumber As Integer
Private InventoryData() As String
Private UBoundInventoryDataRows As Integer
Private UBoundInventoryDataColumns As Integer

Public Property Get GetUBoundInventoryDataRows() As Integer
GetUBoundInventoryDataRows = UBoundInventoryDataRows
End Property

Public Property Get GetUBoundInventoryDataColumns() As Integer
GetUBoundInventoryDataColumns = UBoundInventoryDataColumns
End Property

Public Property Get GetInventoryData() As String()
GetInventoryData = InventoryData
End Property

Public Property Let SPath(Text As String)
Path = Text
End Property

Public Sub AllocateInventoryData()
Dim tempArray() As String
Dim TempLineArray() As String
Dim ColumnArray() As String
Dim FileContent As String
Dim i, j As Integer
TextFileNumber = FreeFile
j = 0
Open Path For Input As TextFileNumber
FileContent = Input(LOF(TextFileNumber), TextFileNumber)
Close TextFileNumber
ColumnArray() = Split(FileContent, vbCrLf)
For i = LBound(ColumnArray) To UBound(ColumnArray)
If LCase(Left(Trim(ColumnArray(i)), 2)) = "mx" Then
ReDim Preserve tempArray(j)
tempArray(j) = Trim(Left(ColumnArray(i), 9)) & ":" & _
Trim(Mid(ColumnArray(i), 10, 9)) & ":" & _
Trim(Mid(ColumnArray(i), 19, 18)) & ":" & _
Trim(Mid(ColumnArray(i), 37, 20)) & ":" & _
Trim(Mid(ColumnArray(i), 57, 4)) & ":" & _
Trim(Mid(ColumnArray(i), 61, 12)) & ":" & _
Trim(Mid(ColumnArray(i), 73, 9)) & ":" & _
Trim(Mid(ColumnArray(i), 82, 9)) & ":" & _
Trim(Mid(ColumnArray(i), 91, 8)) & ":" & _
Trim(Mid(ColumnArray(i), 99, 6)) & ":" & _
Trim(Mid(ColumnArray(i), 105, 9)) & ":" & _
Trim(Mid(ColumnArray(i), 114, 6)) & ":" & _
Trim(Mid(ColumnArray(i), 120, 4)) & ":" & _
Trim(Mid(ColumnArray(i), 124, 3))
j = j + 1
End If
Next i
'in a normal module we shall transpose this next array.
'I did this in this way because of redim agreement
' "the last dimension only could be re-dimensioned" 
ReDim InventoryData(13, UBound(tempArray))
For i = LBound(tempArray) To 13
For j = LBound(tempArray) To UBound(tempArray)
TempLineArray = Split(tempArray(j), ":")
InventoryData(i, j) = TempLineArray(i)
Next j
Next i
UBoundInventoryDataRows = UBound(InventoryData, 1)
UBoundInventoryDataColumns = UBound(InventoryData, 2)
End Sub
```

and here the simple module

```
Option Explicit
Sub example()
Dim cinv As CInventory
Set cinv = New CInventory
cinv.SPath = "H:\Joel\invent_2.prn"
cinv.AllocateInventoryData
Dim row, column As Integer
row = cinv.GetUBoundInventoryDataRows
column = cinv.GetUBoundInventoryDataColumns
Dim Destination As Range
Set Destination = Range("a1")
Destination.Resize(column, row).Value = Application.Transpose(cinv.GetInventoryData)
Set cinv = Nothing
End Sub
```